How fast does a pulsar lose its mass?
I was reading about pulsars, and that they do lose mass over time. How fast do they lose their mass?
I have seen somewhere that our sun loses 4 million tons of mass every second. I imagine a pulsar being 1.3 the mass of our sun losing mass faster than our sun.

A pulsar is a young neutron star, so it's quite different to a main sequence star like the Sun, and has a much smaller surface area.
